# Problems with nested Recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have data from Firebase data like below:

[image]

My problem is my RecyclerView display not as expected. The data of my `messages` were accumulated, it should go one part by one part and should not be accumulated. I do not know how to explain properly since it has so much codes.

My current output shown as below:

[image]

Ask Teacher List Page:

```
package xxx.xxx.my.package

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout;
import com.github.florent37.fiftyshadesof.FiftyShadesOf;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.activity.lesson.LessonActivity;
import com.material.components.adapter.AdapterAskTeacherList;
import com.material.components.adapter.AdapterQuestionToTeacher;
import com.material.components.model.AskTeacherInfo;
import com.material.components.model.AskTeacherItems;
import com.material.components.model.Chapter;
import com.material.components.model.QuestionsToTeacher;
import com.material.components.model.SubChapter;
import com.material.components.model.Subject;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class AskTeacherList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<AskTeacherItems> askTeacherItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterAskTeacherList adapterAskTeacherList;
    private RecyclerView askTeacherListRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewQuestions;
    private SharedPreferences eduYearSharedPreferences;
    private FiftyShadesOf fiftyShadesOf;
    private RelativeLayout layout1;
    private SharedPreferences analysisSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editorAnalysisPreferences;
    public ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterQuestionToTeacher adapterQuestionToTeacher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ask_teacher_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        analysisSharedPreferences  = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AnalysisSharedPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        editorAnalysisPreferences = analysisSharedPreferences.edit();

        adapterAskTeacherList = new AdapterAskTeacherList(askTeacherItemsList, questionsToTeacherList, getApplicationContext());
        askTeacherListRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.askTeacherListRecyclerView);
        layout1 = findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        fiftyShadesOf = FiftyShadesOf.with(this).on(R.id.layout1).start();
        fiftyShadesOf.start();

        askTeacherListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        askTeacherListRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        askTeacherListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        askTeacherListRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        askTeacherListRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAskTeacherList);
        adapterAskTeacherList.setOnClickListener(new AdapterAskTeacherList.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, AskTeacherItems obj, int pos) {
                /*
                Intent gotoLesson = new Intent(AskTeacherList.this, LessonActivity.class);
                gotoLesson.putExtra("subchapter_id",obj.subChapterId);
                gotoLesson.putExtra("subChapterTitle",obj.subChapterTitle);
                editorAnalysisPreferences.putString("subchapterId",obj.subChapterId);
                editorAnalysisPreferences.commit();
                startActivity(gotoLesson);
                */
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, AskTeacherItems obj, int pos) {

            }
        });

        displayAskTeacherItems();
/*

        adapterQuestionToTeacher = new AdapterQuestionToTeacher(questionsToTeacherList);
        recyclerViewQuestions = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewQuestions);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

        recyclerViewQuestions.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewQuestions.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewQuestions.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerViewQuestions.setAdapter(adapterQuestionToTeacher);*/



        eduYearSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("EduYearPreferences",   MODE_PRIVATE);
        showAdminMessage();

    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;
    private BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;
    private View bottom_sheet;
    private void showAdminMessage()
    {
        bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_admin_message);
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);

        if (mBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }

        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet_basic, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText("Test Name");
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(R.string.middle_lorem_ipsum);
        (view.findViewById(R.id.bt_close)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        (view.findViewById(R.id.bt_details)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }

        mBottomSheetDialog.show();
        mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mBottomSheetDialog = null;
            }
        });
    }

    private SubChapter subChapter;
    private  HashMap<String,String> dataAskTeacher = new HashMap<>();
    private void displayAskTeacherItems()
    {
        askTeacherItemsList.clear();
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uuid = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = builder.create();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ask_teachers/students/"+uuid+"/subjects")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            final String subjectId = snapshot.getKey();
                            System.out.println("ssss--subject_id:-"+subjectId);
                            String eduYearId = eduYearSharedPreferences.getString("eduYearValue","");


                            //Chapters label
                            for(DataSnapshot chapterLabel: snapshot.getChildren()){
                                //Chapter data
                                for(DataSnapshot chapterData: chapterLabel.getChildren())
                                {
                                    final String chapterId = chapterData.getKey();
                                    System.out.println("ssss--chapter_id:-"+chapterId);
                                    //Subchapter label
                                    for(DataSnapshot subChapterLabel: chapterData.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        //Subchapter Data
                                        for(DataSnapshot subChapterData: subChapterLabel.getChildren())
                                        {
                                            final String subchapterId = subChapterData.getKey();


                                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("subjects/"+eduYearId+"/data_subject/"+subjectId)
                                                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSubjectSnapshot) {
                                                                String subjectReceived = gson.toJson(dataSubjectSnapshot.getValue());

                                                                if(!subjectReceived.equals("null"))
                                                                {
                                                                    Subject subject = gson.fromJson(subjectReceived,Subject.class);

                                                                    dataAskTeacher.put("subject_title",subject.subjectName);
                                                                }


                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chapters/"+subjectId+"/chapters/"+chapterId)
                                                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataChapterSnapshot) {

                                                                String chaptersReceived = gson.toJson(dataChapterSnapshot.getValue());

                                                                if(!chaptersReceived.equals("null"))
                                                                {
                                                                    System.out.println(chaptersReceived);
                                                                    Chapter chapter = gson.fromJson(chaptersReceived,Chapter.class);

                                                                    System.out.println("chapters---------");
                                                                    System.out.println(chapter.chapterTitle);
                                                                    dataAskTeacher.put("chapter_title",chapter.chapterTitle);
                                                                }

                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("subchapters/"+chapterId+"/subchapters_data/"+subchapterId)
                                                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSubChapterSnapshot) {
                                                                String dataSubChaptersReceived = gson.toJson(dataSubChapterSnapshot.getValue());

                                                                if(!dataSubChaptersReceived.equals("null"))
                                                                {
                                                                    fiftyShadesOf.stop();
                                                                    layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                                                    System.out.println("data subchapters----------------------");
                                                                    System.out.println(dataSubChaptersReceived);
                                                                    subChapter = gson.fromJson(dataSubChaptersReceived,SubChapter.class);
                                                                    dataAskTeacher.put("subchapter_title",subChapter.subchapterTitle);
                                                                    dataAskTeacher.put("subchapter_id",subChapter.subchapterId);

                                                                    System.out.println("subbbbb----"+subChapter.subchapterId);

                                                                    String dataAskTeacherReceived = gson.toJson(dataAskTeacher);
                                                                    AskTeacherItems askTeacherItems = gson.fromJson(dataAskTeacherReceived,AskTeacherItems.class);

                                                                    askTeacherItemsList.add(askTeacherItems);
                                                                    adapterAskTeacherList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                                }
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                            }

                                                        });



                                                //Messages Label
                                            System.out.println("subjechapterId...."+subchapterId);


                                            for(DataSnapshot messagesLabel: subChapterData.getChildren())
                                            {
                                                //Messages Data
                                                for(DataSnapshot messagesData: messagesLabel.getChildren())
                                                {
                                                    String messageQuestion = gson.toJson(messagesData.getValue());
                                                    QuestionsToTeacher questionsToTeacher = gson.fromJson(messageQuestion,QuestionsToTeacher.class);

                                                    //Problem start here
                                                    questionsToTeacherList.add(questionsToTeacher); 
                                                    System.out.println(questionsToTeacher.messages+"    "+questionsToTeacher.questionStatus);
                                                }
                                            }


                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }








                        }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Adapter Ask Teacher List

```
package xxx.xxx.my.package


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.activity.askteachers.AskTeacherList;
import com.material.components.model.AskTeacherInfo;
import com.material.components.model.AskTeacherItems;
import com.material.components.model.QuestionsToTeacher;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterAskTeacherList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<AskTeacherItems> askTeacherListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnClickListener onClickListener = null;
    private List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public AdapterAskTeacherList(List<AskTeacherItems> askTeacherListItems, List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList, Context context) {
        this.askTeacherListItems = askTeacherListItems;
        this.questionsToTeacherList = questionsToTeacherList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_ask_teacher_list,parent,false);

        vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(holder instanceof  OriginalViewHolder)
        {
            OriginalViewHolder view = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;
            final AskTeacherItems askTeacherItems = askTeacherListItems.get(position);
            view.askTeacherStatus.setText(askTeacherItems.askTeacherStatus);
            view.dtCreated.setText(askTeacherItems.dtCreated);
            view.subjectTitle.setText(askTeacherItems.subjectTitle);
            view.chapterTitle.setText(askTeacherItems.chapterTitle);
            view.subchapter.setText(askTeacherItems.subChapterTitle);

            view.lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(onClickListener == null) return;
                    onClickListener.onItemClick(v,askTeacherItems,position);
                }
            });

            view.lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if (onClickListener == null) return false;
                    onClickListener.onItemLongClick(v, askTeacherItems, position);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

            view.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            view.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            view.recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

            AdapterQuestionToTeacher adapterQuestionToTeacher = new AdapterQuestionToTeacher(questionsToTeacherList);

            view.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterQuestionToTeacher);


        }
    }


    public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public View lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list;
        public TextView subjectTitle, chapterTitle,subchapter,askTeacherStatus,dtCreated;
        public RelativeLayout lyt_checked, lyt_image;
        public RecyclerView recyclerView;
        public OriginalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list);
            subjectTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectTitle);
            chapterTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chapterTitle);
            subchapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subchapter);
            askTeacherStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.askTeacherStatus);
            dtCreated = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dtCreated);
            lyt_checked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_checked);
            lyt_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyt_image);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewQuestions);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return askTeacherListItems.size();
    }


    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, AskTeacherItems obj, int pos);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, AskTeacherItems obj, int pos);
    }
}
```

AdapterQuestionToTeacher

```
package xxx.xxx.my.package;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.model.QuestionsToTeacher;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterQuestionToTeacher extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();
    public AdapterQuestionToTeacher(List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList) {
        this.questionsToTeacherList = questionsToTeacherList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_ask_teacher_question,parent,false);
        vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView questionStatus,messages;
        public OriginalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            questionStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionStatus);
            messages = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messages);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof  OriginalViewHolder)
        {
            OriginalViewHolder view = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;
            final QuestionsToTeacher questionsToTeacher = questionsToTeacherList.get(position);
            view.questionStatus.setText(questionsToTeacher.questionStatus);
            view.messages.setText(questionsToTeacher.messages);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return questionsToTeacherList.size();
    }
}
```

content_ask_teacher_list.xml

```
<include android:id="@+id/layout1" layout="@layout/item_ask_teacher_list" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/askTeacherListRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

item_ask_teacher_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_parent_ask_teacher_list"
    style="@style/RippleStyleBlack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewQuestions"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dottedHorizontalRule"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your code looks like a big mess. You are doing also 6 for loops(overkill). I know this does not answer question but it was observation

Comment: I'm newbie in android... huhu..so any advice?

Comment: Can u post ur layout code, i am guessing ur using this aproach:

RecycleView
   -> RecycleView => (here the data gets repeated because it will have the previous data and his data too). I am thinking it will be more clean to do all that staff in your first RecycleView, generating all by code. If u want to go with ur aproach please ensure that questionsToTeacherList in onBindViewHolder method of the first adapter update the questions for the right iteration

Comment: I will update later. I got meeting. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Catluc I've added my layout view code.

Comment: @Nere code very big mess, can tell what is required?

Comment: @RahulDevanavar my problems is regarding on  RecycleView -> RecycleView. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What problem your facing..?pls post what is your requirement

Comment: I do not know how to use recyclerview in another recycler view. Based on picture above, the data were accumulated. It should be 1 part by 1 part.. What I means is like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2DgT.png

Comment: I would recommend to map your data from the firebase values to some kind of object that represents one of those cards. Then you can probably split up the for-loops in smaller units. Right now it is pretty hard to understand what is going on and that is probably part of the reason for your issues in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to point at one specific place and say "this is the issue," since there's a lot of code. But it boils down to the fact that there's only a single `List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList` inside `AdapterAskTeacherList`.

Instead, you should have a `List<List<QuestionsToTeacher>>`. That is, a **list of lists**.

To accomplish this, you'll have to change both the Activity and the outer Adapter. In the activity, change this:

```
public ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();

...

for(DataSnapshot messagesLabel: subChapterData.getChildren())
{
    //Messages Data
    for(DataSnapshot messagesData: messagesLabel.getChildren())
    {
        String messageQuestion = gson.toJson(messagesData.getValue());
        QuestionsToTeacher questionsToTeacher = gson.fromJson(messageQuestion,QuestionsToTeacher.class);

        //Problem start here
        questionsToTeacherList.add(questionsToTeacher); 
        System.out.println(questionsToTeacher.messages+"    "+questionsToTeacher.questionStatus);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();

...

for(DataSnapshot messagesLabel: subChapterData.getChildren())
{
    ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher> sublist = new ArrayList<>();
    //Messages Data
    for(DataSnapshot messagesData: messagesLabel.getChildren())
    {
        String messageQuestion = gson.toJson(messagesData.getValue());
        QuestionsToTeacher questionsToTeacher = gson.fromJson(messageQuestion,QuestionsToTeacher.class);

        //Problem start here
        sublist.add(questionsToTeacher); 
        System.out.println(questionsToTeacher.messages+"    "+questionsToTeacher.questionStatus);
    }
    questionsToTeacherList.add(sublist);
}
```

What you're doing here is taking the `ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>` (the list of questions) and changing it to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>>` (a list of lists of questions). And then, as you read the data out of the database, you create multiple `ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>` and add them to the list of lists.

Then, in your adapter, change this:

```
private List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterAskTeacherList(List<AskTeacherItems> askTeacherListItems, List<QuestionsToTeacher> questionsToTeacherList, Context context) {
    ...
    this.questionsToTeacherList = questionsToTeacherList;
    ...
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ...
        AdapterQuestionToTeacher adapterQuestionToTeacher = new AdapterQuestionToTeacher(questionsToTeacherList);
        view.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterQuestionToTeacher);
        ...
}
```

to this:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>> questionsToTeacherList = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterAskTeacherList(List<AskTeacherItems> askTeacherListItems, ArrayList<ArrayList<QuestionsToTeacher>> questionsToTeacherList, Context context) {
    this.questionsToTeacherList = questionsToTeacherList;
    ...
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ...
        List<QuestionsToTeacher> sublist = questionsToTeacherList.get(position);
        AdapterQuestionToTeacher adapterQuestionToTeacher = new AdapterQuestionToTeacher(sublist);
        view.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterQuestionToTeacher);
        ...
}
```

Again, you're changing the adapter to accept a list of lists of questions (instead of just a list of questions). The key is that you then pass only a single list of questions to each nested RecyclerView.

Comment: Finally...thanks! I appreciated your answer... I'll try first.